# Oracle autoincrement in SQLAlchemy 1.3

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

The SQLAlchemy 1.3 documentation for the dialect Oracle 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html
says

> Since Oracle has no “autoincrement” feature, SQLAlchemy relies upon sequences to produce these values. > With the Oracle dialect, a sequence must always be explicitly specified to enable autoincrement. This > is divergent with the majority of documentation examples which assume the usage of an autoincrement- capable database.

As the autoincrement feature was added in Oracle 12c, I was wondering if it is really not supported by SQLAlchemy yet? Even in the documentation of the prerelease of version 1.4 the above text about autoincrement in Oracle is repeated.  So, at the end of 2019, is the recommended solution to work with a sequence as suggested in the documentation or does anyone know of an autoincrement support for Oracle by SQLAlchemy and could point me to a reference?
Many thanks in advance!